# Display related child info

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I'm trying to display related child information in apex form a query and I can't seem to get the right field value. I"m sure it's just my syntax:

my class code is:

```
public with sharing class AccountsinPlacesExt
{

    public Place__c place { get; private set; }
    public List<Account> inPlaceAccounts { get; private set; }
    public AccountsinPlacesExt(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        // add the Place__c field that tells you which state
        List<String> neededFields = new List<String> { 'City__c','State_Code__c' };
        if (!Test.isRunningTest()) controller.addFields(neededFields);
        place = (Place__c)controller.getRecord();

       if (place.City__c != null) {
       // search for city and state match
            inPlaceAccounts = [
                SELECT Name, (SELECT Service__r.Name FROM ServiceAccountAssociations__r),(SELECT Name FROM Contacts)  FROM Account
                WHERE Service_Count__c > 0 AND BillingCity = :place.City__c AND BillingState = :place.State_Code__c
            ];
       } else {
       //search for only state match
            inPlaceAccounts = [
                SELECT Name, (SELECT Service__r.Name FROM ServiceAccountAssociations__r),(SELECT Name FROM Contacts)  FROM Account
                WHERE Service_Count__c > 0 AND BillingState = :place.State_Code__c
            ];
       }
       // end else
    }

}
```

Here's two that work:

```
<apex:column> 
    <apex:facet name="header">Account Name</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputLink value="/one/one.app#/sObject/{!Account.id}/view">
        {!Account.name}
    </apex:outputLink>
</apex:column>
<apex:column>
    <apex:facet name="header">Contact Name</apex:facet>
    <apex:repeat value="{!account.Contacts}" var="contact">
        <apex:outputLink value="/one/one.app#/sObject/{!contact.id}/view">
            {!contact.name}
        </apex:outputLink>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:column>
```

this is what i'm trying:

```
<apex:column>
    <apex:facet name="header">Services</apex:facet>
    <apex:repeat var="service"
        value="{!account.ServiceAccountAssociations__r.Service__c}">
        <apex:outputLink value="/one/one.app#/sObject/{!service.id}/view">
            {!service.name}
        </apex:outputLink>;
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:column>
```

something doesn't add up here.

The error I get is:

```
Error: Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.Service__c'
```

Comment: pls share your code.

Comment: i just shared but my code disappeared.

Comment: May be in your query you are missing Service__c field in the Apex code.

Comment: I have (SELECT Service__r.Name FROM ServiceAccountAssociations__r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an explanation to why your loop is wrong, if you set

```
<apex:repeat var="junction" value="{!account.ServiceAccountAssociations__r}">
```

its `Apex` equivalent would be:

```
for (ServiceAccountAssociation__c junction : account.ServiceAccountAssociations__r)
```

Notice that you could retrieve `junction.Service__r.Name`. The `SObjectType` is `ServiceAccountAssociation__c`, not `Service__c`.

Comment: i wish I understood the apex equivalent code, and how to decipher it in the for loop - I don't get what i'm really iterating on here... but alas, it works.

Comment: @soxdave See: [Loops](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops.htm)